# How can I solve $23^{2m}\equiv 73 \left (\text{mod } 1971 \right )$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Solutions for $m \in{N} $. The original equation says that $27 \times 23^{2m}\equiv 0 \left ( \text{mod }1971 \right), $ and therefore I concluded that the congruence above holds, because $27\times 73 = 1971$. I hope my conclusion is true and that you can help me.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $27\times23^{2m}\equiv0\bmod1971=27\times73$ means $23^{2m}\equiv0\bmod73$, which has no solutions

Comment: It's also easy enough to check computationally that the equations have no solution: $23^{2m}$ cycles through 18 values, as $23^{36} \equiv 1 \bmod 1971$.  The values are 1, 529, 1930, 1963, 1681, 328, 64, 349, 1318, 1459, 1150, 1282, 154, 655, 1570, 739, 673, 1237.

Comment: Not sure why you'd thing $27*23^{2m}\equiv 0\pmod{27*23}$ would mean $23^{2m}\equiv 73\pmod {1971}$.  It'd mean $23^{2m]\equiv 0 \pmod {73}$.

Answer (score 1):

> The original equation says that $27 \times 23^{2m}\equiv 0 \left ( \text{mod }1971 \right) $

From this, you should have concluded that $23^{2m}\equiv0\bmod73$.

($27\times 23^{2m}\equiv0\bmod1971\iff 1971|27\times23^{2m}\iff73|23^{2m}\iff23^{2m}\equiv0\bmod73.)$

Furthermore, this has no solutions, because $23$ and $73$ are different primes, so $73\nmid23^{2m}$.